# I want to insert a record in DB and then need to return a row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, return, code-behind

I want to insert a record in DB and then need to return a row. I created the query but how to use that in .cs (C# code)

This is my query

```
 @ledgerId numeric(18,0) ,
 @voucherNo varchar(MAX) ,
 @invoiceNo varchar(MAX) ,
 @date datetime ,
 @month datetime ,
 @totalAmount decimal(18,5) ,
 @narration varchar(MAX) ,
-- @extraDate datetime ,
 @extra1 varchar(MAX) ,
 @extra2 varchar(MAX) ,
 @suffixPrefixId numeric(18,0) ,
 @voucherTypeId numeric(18,0) 
AS
DECLARE @UpdatedVoucherNo DECIMAL(18,0)

SET @UpdatedVoucherNo = (SELECT ISNULL( MAX(CAST (voucherNo AS NUMERIC(18,0))),0) + 1
 FROM tbl_SalaryVoucherMaster
 WHERE voucherTypeId=@voucherTypeId)

 IF (@UpdatedVoucherNo = @voucherNo )

 INSERT INTO tbl_SalaryVoucherMaster
 (
            /*salaryVoucherMasterId,*/
            ledgerId,
            voucherNo,
            invoiceNo,
            date,
            month,
            totalAmount,
            narration,
            extraDate,
            extra1,
            extra2,
            suffixPrefixId,
            voucherTypeId )
VALUES
 (
            /*@salaryVoucherMasterId, */
            @ledgerId, 
            @voucherNo, 
            @invoiceNo, 
            @date, 
            @month, 
            @totalAmount, 
            @narration, 
            getDate(), 
            @extra1, 
            @extra2,
            @suffixPrefixId,
            @voucherTypeId)

            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [Identity],0 AS [UpdatedVoucherNo]
```

Comment: do you know the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do what you want is to modify `@voucherNo` to be an `OUTPUT` parameter, and add a new `OUTPUT` parameter to your query to return the value of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

```
@voucherNo varchar(max)
@ScopeIdentity numeric(38,0)
```

And modify that last `SELECT` statement to set the value of @ScopeIdentity parameter.

```
SELECT @ScopeIdentity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Then use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` to execute the query, and on completion, read the values from the output parameters.

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(connection, commandText))
{
    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (rowsAffected > 0)
    {
        var voucherNo = (string)command.Parameters["@voucherNo].Value;
        var identity = (decimal)command.Parameters["@ScopeIdentity"].Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Command.ExecuteNonQuery();` is what you need, it returns the number(`int`) of rows affected in inserting and updating data,

here is an example to use it,

```
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn ;
            SqlCommand cmd ;
            string sql = null;

            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            sql = "Your SQL Statemnt Here";

            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

                cnn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
                int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    //do anything
                }
                cmd.Dispose();
                cnn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show (" ExecuteNonQuery in SqlCommand executed !!");
```

more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

Comment: NO i just want to insert a data to table and need to return the columns in the "select" statment

Comment: first i want to insert then i need to get the values of columns in the select statement i got the query but i want to know how i can implement it on Code. for insertion i need executeNonquery.. and for return a row i used dataAdaptor and i want to use it same time.. but its not working

Comment: what do you mean, return the columns?

Comment: do you mean, the data you inserted?

Comment: then use the `Select` statement and `SqlDataReader`

Comment: yes i want to get the identity(scope_identity() )and the inserted voucher number